# Scrapy spider web scraping code gives no output

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, scrapy

I am new to scrapy and Ubuntu 20 but have decent knowledge of functional and oops programing in Python. 
I just tried the very first basic tutorial spider from [Scrapy docs] (https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/tutorial.html) titled Extracting data in our spider.

I tried to run it but it did not work.

**I wish to get the quote and author printed on terminal!!!**

Thanks in Advance :)))))

This is the code

```
import scrapy

class FmSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'fm'
    def begin(self):
        allowed_domains = ['http://quotes.toscrape.com/']
        start_urls = ['http://quotes.toscrape.com/']

        for url in start_urls:
            yield scrapy.Request(url= url, callback= self.parse)

    def parse(self, response):
        
        for quote in response.css("div.quote"):
            yield {
                "quote": quote.css("span.text::text").get,
                "author": quote.css("small.author::text").get
            }
```

*This is the terminal output*

```
(venv) atul@vivobook:/media/atul/New Volume/Ubuntu/Code Projects/Web scraping/scrapy-tut$ scrapy runspider fm.py
2022-01-13 18:43:29 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Scrapy 2.5.1 started (bot: scrapybot)
2022-01-13 18:43:29 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Versions: lxml 4.7.1.0, libxml2 2.9.12, cssselect 1.1.0, parsel 1.6.0, w3lib 1.22.0, Twisted 21.7.0, Python 3.10.1 (main, Jan  7 2022, 19:42:47) [GCC 9.3.0], pyOpenSSL 21.0.0 (OpenSSL 1.1.1m  14 Dec 2021), cryptography 36.0.1, Platform Linux-5.11.0-46-generic-x86_64-with-glibc2.31
2022-01-13 18:43:29 [scrapy.utils.log] DEBUG: Using reactor: twisted.internet.epollreactor.EPollReactor
2022-01-13 18:43:30 [scrapy.crawler] INFO: Overridden settings:
{'SPIDER_LOADER_WARN_ONLY': True}
2022-01-13 18:43:30 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] INFO: Telnet Password: 52c66eea99a19657
2022-01-13 18:43:30 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled extensions:
['scrapy.extensions.corestats.CoreStats',
 'scrapy.extensions.telnet.TelnetConsole',
 'scrapy.extensions.memusage.MemoryUsage',
 'scrapy.extensions.logstats.LogStats']
2022-01-13 18:43:30 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled downloader middlewares:
['scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpauth.HttpAuthMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.downloadtimeout.DownloadTimeoutMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.defaultheaders.DefaultHeadersMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.useragent.UserAgentMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry.RetryMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.MetaRefreshMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpcompression.HttpCompressionMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.RedirectMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.cookies.CookiesMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpproxy.HttpProxyMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.stats.DownloaderStats']
2022-01-13 18:43:30 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled spider middlewares:
['scrapy.spidermiddlewares.httperror.HttpErrorMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.offsite.OffsiteMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.referer.RefererMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.urllength.UrlLengthMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.depth.DepthMiddleware']
2022-01-13 18:43:30 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled item pipelines:
[]
2022-01-13 18:43:30 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider opened
2022-01-13 18:43:30 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2022-01-13 18:43:30 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] INFO: Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6023
2022-01-13 18:43:30 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
2022-01-13 18:43:30 [scrapy.statscollectors] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
{'elapsed_time_seconds': 0.016834,
 'finish_reason': 'finished',
 'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2022, 1, 13, 13, 13, 30, 895311),
 'log_count/INFO': 10,
 'memusage/max': 57552896,
 'memusage/startup': 57552896,
 'start_time': datetime.datetime(2022, 1, 13, 13, 13, 30, 878477)}
2022-01-13 18:43:30 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider closed (finished)
(venv) atul@vivobook:/media/atul/New Volume/Ubuntu/Code Projects/Web scraping/scrapy-tut$
```

Comment: So... what's your question?

Comment: I wish to get the quote and and author printed in terminal. How to do it?

Comment: you define a class. where do you instantiate that class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `parse` method will be called for every url in `start_urls`, so you don't need the `begin` function (where did you get this?). If you really want to call the `parse` method then do it with `start_requests`.

See the example [here](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html?highlight=start_requests#scrapy.spiders.Spider.start_requests).

With start_requests:

```py
import scrapy


class FmSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'fm'
    allowed_domains = ['quotes.toscrape.com']
    start_urls = ['http://quotes.toscrape.com']

    def start_requests(self):
        for url in self.start_urls:
            yield scrapy.Request(url=url, callback=self.parse)

    def parse(self, response):
        for quote in response.css("div.quote"):
            yield {
                "quote": quote.css("span.text::text").get(),
                "author": quote.css("small.author::text").get()
            }
```

And if you lose the `start_requests` it won't matter. When to use `start_requests`? For example if you want to add headers, proxy, anything you want to do before creating the requests.

Comment: Thanks, now I get it. I forgot to put () after get and that start_urls should be out of function because its a class property.